# Create Jacoco report for external repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a Spring-Boot maven repository. I can't alter pom.xml to add jacoco-maven-plugin. But I need a test coverage report for this repository.

So my idea was to execute the following command:

```
mvn clean verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report
```

But in the logs I see:

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:prepare-agent (default-cli) @ backend ---
[INFO] argLine set to -javaagent:C:\\Users\\admin\\.m2\\repository\\org\\jacoco\\org.jacoco.agent\\0.8.6\\org.jacoco.agent-0.8.6-runtime.jar=destfile=C:\\projects\\my-project\\backend\\target\\jacoco.exec
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.6:report (default-cli) @ backend ---
[INFO] Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file.
```

and no report is generated.

What should I do to add "missing execution data file"? And is it even possible to generate Jacoco report without adding anything to the pom.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this thing out. Turns out I needed to change the goal's order a bit.

Instead of:
`mvn clean verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report`

1. Clean.
2. Verify.
3. Prepare Jacoco Agent.
4. Build report.

I need to do:

1. Clean
2. Prepare Jacoco Agent
3. Verify
4. Build report.

   `mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent verify org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report`

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, clean everything, attach the plugin, run tests with the plugin attached and generate the report